# Where does Borderlands 2 store save files?

Tags: pc, borderlands-2

Where is the save file location? I've upgraded to Windows 8 and am barely been able to start the game. After some tweaks with compatibility, the game starts, but all my configs and saves are gone.

Where do I need to look to find my save files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Borderlands 2's save game location is at `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\(Random Numbers)`

Source: [PC Gaming Wiki's Borderlands 2 article](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderlands_2#Game_Data)

Comment: I see my save file is dated from Oct 24... It's like the game don't see it, how can I force the game to load from this location then ?

Comment: @Warface How many folders with random numbers do you see in the 'SaveData' folder? You might need to transfer the contents of the older folder to a newer one, if there are multiple, random number folders.

Comment: Only 1 folder with 1 random number.

Comment: @Warface Try starting a new game and then saving, see if it creates a new 'random number' folder in the 'SaveData' folder. If a new folder was created, try transferring the contents of the old folder to it. (Also backup the only 'random number' directory to another location before trying, just to make sure it does not get overwritten.)

Comment: Well I'll try when the game will be playable, when I select new game the intro is lagging like hell. UNPLAYABLE on Win8 what a shame...

Comment: @Warface Try [disabling the intro movies](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderlands_2#Disabling_Intro_Movies). (If the instructions in the previous link does not work, [try the instructions here](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=2975353&postcount=4).) Also, if the save game transfer still does not work, try stopping cloud storage in the Borderlands 2 Steam properties, and then try [the method I described again](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90352/wheres-borderlands-2-save-files/90353#comment124511_90353).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if Windows 8 has a shadowing service or something (an extension of the library concept).  It could be possible that the actual physical location for common folders is in a different location but also references the "legacy" paths.

Comment: @Warface Did you do an upgrade installation, or a fresh install?  If it's the later, there may be file permission problems associated with your old  account.

Answer (score 2):

Save Files / Save Games:

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\`
- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/SaveData/`
- Linux: `~/Library/Application Support/RogueLegacy/`

To find the path

- Windows: Open file explore > Paste the path > Press enter
- Mac: Command + SHIFT + G > Paste the path > Press go

Configuration Files:

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\Config\`
- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/Config/`
- Linux: `$XDG_DATA_HOME/aspyr-media/borderlands 2/willowgame/config/`

Source: [FileLocations](https://www.filelocations.com/borderlands-2-save-location/)