# Borderlands 2 - Missing Documents folder - (likely) person specific problem

Tags: borderlands-2

So i run a Windows 10 machine with a GTX 750 Ti, and a AMD FX-6300 6 core Processor. This machine **WAS** running with two drives. 1 120GB SSD, and 1 1TB HDD. My Documents, Pictures, and Music Folders were on the 1TB drive, and about a month ago, my 1TB drive **failed**. I was able to dig up an old 450GB HDD, that used to house Windows 7, on an HP Envy(not sure specific details.) Notebook. This drive has some games on it, one of which being Borderlands. There are some very OLD borderlands saves on this drive, however, borderlands cannot see them.

Now, out of the hope i will be able to recover this 1TB hard drive, i've tried my best to not modify registry values, or library locations(really anything that may make the system not run as it had before), and i think i haven't modified anything.

So now to the question. Where might Borderlands 2(Running off steam), store it's save files, if the default save location cannot be accessed?(In this case, can't be accessed because the drive is gone.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event that borderlands 2 cannot write to a save location such as your documents folder, it will create a folder in its execution directory, for saving files.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Borderlands 2\Binaries\Win32\\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\76561198079075928
```

Yes the double "\\" after "Win32" is actually meant to be there.

Answer (score 0):

> Borderlands 2's save game location is at
>   C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands
>   2\WillowGame\SaveData(Random Numbers)

Source: [Stack Exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90352/where-does-borderlands-2-store-save-files)

However, Borderlands 2 has Steam cloud saving, so if your last PC was connected to the internet, it should've periodically synced Borderlands 2's saves to the steam cloud, and they should be there upon relaunching the game after reinstall.
Steam Cloud also saves your saves in:

> C:\Program Files\Steam\userdata\UserID\20920\Remote Check if there is
>   any content in the remote map. In this map, Cloud stores your cloud
>   savegames.

Source: [Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2835542)

Comment: "**My Documents**, Pictures, and Music Folders were on the 1TB drive, and about a month ago, my 1TB drive **failed**." :(

Comment: @Luna "However, Borderlands 2 has Steam cloud saving, so if your last PC was connected to the internet, it should've periodically synced Borderlands 2's saves to the steam cloud, and they should be there upon relaunching the game after reinstall. 
"

Comment: I should elaborate on that statement more. Basically before, Borderlands was saving to D:\Documents, and now it's not saving to C:\(SSD) or H:\(Old Drive)

Comment: There are no  saves accessible in borderlands, but steam claims to have saves.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the steam cloud location? It might be there.

Comment: Yea that's what i meant by steam claims to have saves.

Comment: Found it. `H:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Borderlands 2\Binaries\Win32\\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\76561198079075928`